# Image not respecting the size of it's parents

Tags: html, css

I'm using flexslider and I'm wrapping the img within a div that is displayed as inline-block. That way, I can contain other elements (a button on hover) inside the same div and position them relatively to that.
It works as expected on Chrome but on Mozilla the image seems to disregard any height or width restrictions set on it's parent elements and display in full size.
Heres a quick codepen that mimics the issue.
http://codepen.io/spylefkaditis/pen/HysBi

Again this works fine on Chrome but not on Mozilla.
Any ideas?

**HTML**:

```
<ul>
  <li>
    <div class="image">
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/1200/1800/" alt="" />
<!--      <a href="#" class="btn">button</a>
      <div class="modal">
        <p class="message"></p>
      </div>-->
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

**SCSS**:

```
*{
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
html,body{
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
}

ul{
  margin:0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height:100%;
  list-style-type:none;


  li{
    display:inline-block;
    position:relative;
    height:100%;
    width: 100%;
    text-align:center;

    .image{
      position:relative;
      display:inline-block;
      text-align:center;

      img{
        display: inline-block;
        max-height:100%;
        width:auto;
      }
/*      
      .btn{
        position:absolute;
        left:0;
        bottom:0;
        background-color:black;
      }
      */
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set a height value to the `.image` element as follows:

```
.image{
  position:relative;
  display:inline-block;
  text-align:center;
  height: inherit;
}
```

Otherwise, the `div.image` expands its height so as to accommodate the content, in this case, the large image.

See demo at: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Hptco

I tested this in Firefox and Chrome and it seems to work okay.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Marc. I did use height 100% before and that seemed to fix the issue EXCEPT that now theres extra spacing around the sides of the img element.
Heres a screenshot of what I mean. 
http://postimg.org/image/bj2r9grpp/

Comment: I see the problem of the extra space between the `img` and `.image` and I am not sure where it comes from.  However, I did find that by setting the width of `.image` to something small like `10px`, it forces the `.image` element to shrink and as a result, the image overflows and there is no whitespace to the sides.  Also, the behavior is not totally concistent between Firefox and Chrome.  I also found that by increasing the height of the window, the image size increases and the whitespace disappears eventually. I can't do much more at this point...

Comment: Thanks for trying to help man. I'm thinking of just throwing JS on it and making it work. When it doubt JS...